# Automatically distribute UWP app

Tags: uwp, azure-devops, devops, software-distribution, visual-studio-app-center

I'm developing an UWP application and I'm trying to set up Build/CI so that the app is automatically published and available to test-users as soon as a build passes. I've managed to deploy the app-package to AppCenter using VSTS, but I cant figure out how to automatically get the package to Microsoft Store or such. Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree. So, what is the proffered way of doing this?

Comment: According to this page, https://appcenter.ms/, what you really want to do is to provide the updated app to your beta testers through the App Center and not to the Microsoft Store. What is in the store is supposed to be validated and tested. And there is this Quick Start https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/get-started-designer?toc=%2Fvsts%2Fuser-guide%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fvsts%2Fuser-guide%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=vsts&tabs=new-nav

Comment: If your have a corporate account then I believe you can use [Microsoft Store API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/create-and-manage-submissions-using-windows-store-services) with Azure authentification, but I haven't tried it myself. I agree with Richard that App Center will be a better option for an individual account.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use the Visual Studio Team Services extension for the Microsoft Store to integrate with the Store API, and send your app package to the Store.

You need to connect your Dev Center account with Azure Active Directory (AD), and then create an app in your AD to authenticate the requests. You can follow the guidance in the extension page to accomplish that.

Once you’ve configured the extension, you can add the build task, and configure it with your app ID and the location of the .appxupload file.

[image]

Where the value of the `Package File` parameter will be:

```
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\
AppxPackages\MyUWPApp__$(AppxVersion)_x86_x64_ARM_bundle.appxupload
```

You have to manually activate this build. You can use it to update existing apps but you can’t use it to for your first submission to the Store. For more information, see [Create and manage Store submissions by using Microsoft Store Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/monetize/create-and-manage-submissions-using-windows-store-services).

Download the task "Windows Store" from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-RDX-MRO.windows-store-publish).